# Set cursor position in contenteditable div using jquery.caret.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, contenteditable

I cannot find a suitable solution to move my cursor to a specific position.

I am getting cursor position using jquery.caret.js

```
 var position=$('#elementContentEditable').caret('pos');
```

How do I set the caret position to a position returned by the above line of code?